# Missing argument error however one is given

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, unsupervised-learning

I have a unsuperivsed learning class and one of the functions is throwing an error for seemingly no reason. My class method that's throwing the error is:

```
def flatten(self,cluster):
    out = []
    for item in cluster:
        if isinstance(item, (list, tuple)):
            out.extend(HC.flatten(item))
        else:
            out.append(item)
    return out
```

Which is a function I have found online,its aruement is a list and it flattens it, the output of the lists that are being entered as the argument up to the list which seems to be throwing the error along with the stated error:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\benti\Group Project 2\HC\Complete Linkage.py"
(51, 98)
(343, 390)
(150, 317)
(7, 209)
(173, 235)
(11, 85)
((343, 390), 82)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\benti\Group Project 2\HC\Complete Linkage.py", line 88, in <module>
    Z= HC.run2()
  File "c:\Users\benti\Group Project 2\HC\Complete Linkage.py", line 82, in run2
    cluster2 = HC.flatten(cluster2)          
  File "c:\Users\benti\Group Project 2\HC\Super.py", line 170, in flatten
    out.extend(HC.flatten(item))
TypeError: flatten() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cluster'

[Done] exited with code=1 in 8.745 seconds
```

I should note I'm using a superclass and am not getting this error thrown within that class.

Comment: Don't use classes as namespaces. That is what modules are there for.

Comment: Okay thanks I will keep that in mind

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you want a static method, remove the `self` argument from the method signature

```
class HC:
    def flatten(cluster): # Only cluster remains
        out = []
        for item in cluster:
            if isinstance(item, (list, tuple)):
                out.extend(HC.flatten(item))
            else:
                out.append(item)
        return out

flatten_test = ((343, 390), 82)
print(HC.flatten(toflatten)) # [343, 390, 82]
```